# How to remove static block from footer at contact us page?

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-us, layout

I have added two static blocks in `footer.phtml`. Now I want to remove the those blocks from footer at contact us page for this I go to `app/design/frontend/default/MY TEmplate/layout/contacts.xml` and in paste the following code there:

```
<reference name="footer">
    <remove name="shopper_footer_banners"/> 
</reference>`
```

Where `shopper_footer_banners` is the name of the block which I want to remove then I will right this code in `local.xml` file but couldn't succeed so anyone please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<remove />` is a node which doesn't need to be inside any other node or reference. It is applied "globally" and last, so wherever you put it, it is applied.

You didn't post your complete `contacs.xml` so I can only guess, but this should work:

```
<contacts_index_index translate="label">
    <remove name="shopper_footer_banners"/>
</contacts_index_index>
```

If it doesn't make sure your block has exactly this name and your layout cache is up to date.